# Order by specific value in column

Tags: mysql

I have a query that works, but I need to change the ORDER BY. I am kinda confused as I do not know if is possible as I have dynamic numbers in front of the second part "3000R3009", "4000R3009"

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Id, Sifra FROM artikli WHERE Sifra like '$sifra[0]%' ORDER BY ArtId asc");
```

I tried to put ORDER BY FILED(Sifra, '%R3009), but it doesn't work. In most cases, I have some numbers before R3009 and I want those numbers to show first in the dropdown. Not sure if this can be done on sql side.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT Id, Sifra FROM artikli WHERE Sifra like '$sifra[0]%' ORDER BY FILED(Sifra, '%R3009");
```

UPDATE
The query can output a result "1000R3000, 1000R6000, 125555R7121, 55R30009" and on top, I want to show 55R30009. If a value contains R3009 it should be on top Multiple values with R3009 cannot happen as there is just one.

Comment: So if the string ends R3009 you want it numerically sorted by the number before that, and all such strings to come first?  Is there ever anything before that isn't a number?  What about the things not ending R3009, how should those be sorted?  Show lots of sample data demonstrating all the types of strings you have and how you want them sorted

Comment: @ysth the value that or if containts R3009 should be on top. For example, query can print "1000R3000, 1000R6000, 125555R7121, 55R30009" and on top, I want to show 55R30009. other ordering not important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just want

```
order by instr(Sifra,'R3009')=0, 0+Sifra
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If digits before 'R' is fixed (assume 4 digits), you can use `SUBSTRING` function, e.g.

```
SELECT Id, Sifra FROM artikli WHERE Sifra like '$sifra[0]%' ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Sifra, 5)
```

Otherwise, you need to use more complex function such as `POSOTION` to find 'R'.

Comment: thanks for helping  I think substring will not work as it is not always in 5th place. for example, the number before R can be 12341233. But there can be R8014 and I need to order where R3009 is always on top if exist in the column.